# Which countries are allowing visitors to overstay their visas due to the Coronavirus outbreak?

Tags: visas, covid-19

Let's say I'm a healthy traveler in a country with relatively few cases of COVID-19, and my tourist visa is expiring soon. Many countries have been instituting [travel bans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_restrictions_related_to_the_2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic#Countries_implementing_a_global_travel_ban) (for *all* incoming travelers, not only those infected), so my choice of destinations is rapidly narrowing down to only my home country. However, if my home country has more cases of Coronavirus disease, comparatively, it would be in the interest of public health worldwide to *not* return there and add to the problem.

Are there any countries that allow travelers to overstay their travel visas due to the extenuating circumstance of the Coronavirus outbreak?

Otherwise, travelers in countries with relatively fewer cases of COVID-19 will practically be forced to leave to countries with effectively a higher chance of dying.

Comment: A foreign country owes nothing to you. Their responsibility is their citizens, and in times of crisis you are an extra mouth to feed and potential patient. It is to their advantage for you to leave. Your only hope is asylum, which will almost certainly fail or normal extension of your visa/stay with a good reason.. Even in _civilized_ Europe, nationalism has taken over.

Comment: @Dan Dascalescu Force majeure would likely apply if you were already in the country and could not leave. How would you prove you are healthy? Health experts have already acknowledged that ‘relatively few cases’ doesn’t mean there are not 00’s or 000’s of undiagnosed / asymptomatic cases. The U.K. being an example - it’s thought unreported cases could be in their 000’s.

Comment: It is not that you would be *allowed* to overstay your visa, it would be that you would be *forced* to remain in the country. If there is a mean to return home you must use it, if there is no way of returning you are forced to remain no matter your opinio...

Comment: Also "it would be in the interest of public health worldwide to not return there and add to the problem." is nonsense. Go back to your country and isolate yourself, and "public health worldwide" will be satisfied.

Comment: @SJuan76 the government's hand forcing you to remain in the country is the same thing as granting permission to remain.

Comment: There is no general rule. A combination of **Force majeure**, humanitarian aspect and how much you would not become a further burden would be the keys to a possible decision. **Political asylum** (to use the correct terminology),  is of course nonsense to suggest in this context.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, there are legal constructions where a foreigner is ordered to leave and that order to leave is then vacated. A different legal category from permission to stay.

Comment: @user56513: "your only hope is asylum, which will almost certainly fail or normal extension of your visa/stay with a good reason" - I think things are not quite that bleak: In January and February, when the virus situation in Europe wasn't yet what it is now, Chinese visitor visas were extended beyond the normal maximum upper limit of 90 days in Germany, and probably other EU countries, precisely due to the coronavirus situation in China at that point. FWIW, visitors still weren't allowed to *overstay* as much as they could have their visas prolonged beyond the regular upper limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My UK visa expires soon, what should I do now during the COVID-19 outbreak?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155088/my-uk-visa-expires-soon-what-should-i-do-now-during-the-covid-19-outbreak)