# My UK visa expires soon, what should I do now during the COVID-19 outbreak?

Tags: uk, overstaying, covid-19, brazilian-citizens

I am a Brazilian citizen actually traveling and volunteering in the UK (been here for 5 months).

I came with a normal visa plus the return ticket (in April **21st**). Right now I'm in Scotland's highlands (this is relevant because I would have to travel quite a bit to get the flight). I can switch to any flight until December **31st**.

My flight back goes through London, Lisboa and then Brazil. This is troublesome as Lisboa border will potentially close. I can think of 3 scenarios:

1. flight goes well and get home (sounds easier than it will be)
2. flight cancelled and postponed for a date after my visa expires
3. Flight-on-date but I don't take the flight to take care of my health and see how this situation evolves.

The question boils down to:

- Is there any way to extend my visa or: is it too bad to stay longer and let it expires?

(I've tried to contact a few governmental entities with no response so far, which is reasonable as they might be overloaded).

**Disclaimer**

As I've said on the bottom of the post, I emailed the embassy. They only replied today and the link they sent points to uk advices for chinese people, and it's completely useless. As I was expecting the flight state is rather uncertain (tap air portugal). You can check the cancelled flights. I would also recommend anyone having a safe chance to go back to do it. This is not the case.

Comment: can't add the proper tags as my phone includes uk + all else that matches. And even if i delete them it deletes all uk*

Comment: Which airline(s) are you booked with? Are all the flights a single booking (one PNR)? Have you contacted the Brazilian Embassy in the UK http://londres.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/? Can you change to a direct flight from London, leaving ASAP?

Comment: Many countries are advising their citizens to return home while they still can. You should make plans to leave as soon as possible. Contact your airline to arrange new flights. If that proves impossible contact your embassy and UKVI to find out what your options are. Rules can be changed at short notice in extreme circumstances. What is not possible today may be perfectly possible tomorrow. Do **not** just let your visa expire.

Comment: Direct flights from London are showing as available in the next few days eg https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en-gb You should return home while you can.

Comment: There is no mechanism to extend a Standard Visitor visa. You might be able to claim force majeure if you were trapped in the UK and had no alternative but to overstay, but currently you do have viable options to leave. As an aside, hopefully you are already aware that there are restrictions on visitors carrying out volunteering activities, see App3 (4) https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: @Traveller thanks a lot guys. I'll be updating in 2 hrs.

Comment: @Arthur's Pass thanks a lot, i'll comment back in 2 hours.

Comment: To be honest, you should already be enroute to your home country.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is related to a rapidly-changing event. Have a read on the relevant governmental websites to answer your question. In addition, get in touch with your local embassy/consulate. These sources of information will surely be correct, as well as up to date.

Comment: South Korea extended many visas automatically, including tourist visas very recently. It is possible that UK takes a similar decision, but of course, there is no guarantee this will happen. You should contact immigration services.

Comment: @JoErNanO I don't agree. Also the post seems to be helpful for more people than just me. You still can re open it if your mind changes. I've made some edits.

Comment: @CGCampbell were I followed your advise, I would be stuck in london. Do not comment just to say what pops up in your mind please. I want to leave the country, but it's not that simple now.

Comment: My "advice" (which wasn't advice, but rather a pithy comment) was EXACTLY the same as the first and second sentences of Anish's answer.

Comment: As at 3:20am GMT, Friday, British Airways and Latam are offering direct flights from London to Rio and Sao Paolo this weekend. I haven't checked further ahead. You can leave. What's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Many countries are advising their citizens to return home while they still can. You should make plans to leave as soon as possible. Contact your airline to arrange new flights. If that proves impossible contact your embassy and UKVI to find out what your options are. Rules can be changed at short notice in extreme circumstances. What is not possible today may be perfectly possible tomorrow. Do **not** just let your visa expire.

There is no mechanism to extend a Standard Visitor visa. You might be able to claim force majeure if you were trapped in the UK and had no alternative but to overstay, but currently you do have viable options to leave. As an aside, hopefully you are already aware that there are restrictions on visitors carrying out volunteering activities, [see App3 (4)](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)

*Compiled from the comments*

Comment: @brazilianTraveler The advice issued by U.K. Immigration https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-immigration-guidance-if-youre-unable-to-return-to-china-from-the-uk may only refer to China however it’s not unreasonable to assume a similar stance will be taken for all visa holders in the UK. The advice doesn’t cover visa-free visitors, from which it seems reasonable to conclude that the expectation is that tourists in the U.K. should follow their country’s advice and return home as soon as possible.